# Evidence to support 20-20-20 rule?

Tags: eye, eye-strain

[American Optometric Association](https://www.aoa.org/healthy-eyes/eye-and-vision-conditions/computer-vision-syndrome):

> The average American worker spends seven hours a day on the computer either in the office or working from home. To help alleviate digital eyestrain, follow the 20-20-20 rule; take a 20-second break to view something 20 feet away every 20 minutes.

[Canadian Association of Optometrists](https://opto.ca/eye-health-library/20-20-20-rule):

> Every 20 minutes, take a 20-second break and focus your eyes on something at least 20 feet away.

(20 feet = 6.096 m)

What evidence is there to support this 20-20-20 rule/recommendation?

---

Related questions:

Where did this rule come from? (It sounds like some folk remedy invented by some layperson.)

Is 20 feet = 6.096 m optimal? Why not 10 or 40 or 200 feet or 2000 feet? (Similar questions for the other two variables of frequency and duration of breaks.)

[Why can't we just close our eyes periodically to reduce eye strain?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/20794/why-cant-we-just-close-our-eyes-periodically-to-reduce-eye-strain)

Comment: Is anyone making the claim that this regimen is optimal? Probably not. Round numbers, memorable phrase, a distance that you'd likely find available in an office environment: practicality is important, too, and elaborate studies to follow people over a long time spread over multiple factorial groups to cover the whole parameter space...not practical.

Answer (score 1):

6 m/20 feet is about the infinity distance for the human eye - actual infinity is infinity, but the accommodation between 6 m and infinity is minimal. this is known as the [Far Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_point).

The actual best practice will be to focus on things further than 6 m, as in the Canadian quote you provided, so as to provide an infinity point - basically any distance 6 m or greater works. If you follow the Canadian link you provided, you will find references to support the

But I agree with the comment from Bryan Krause - keep it simple and memorable and it is more likely to get complied with. Indeed I found an [Optometry Times article](https://www.optometrytimes.com/view/deconstructing-20-20-20-rule-digital-eye-strain)<sup>1</sup> where the author tracked down the originator of the phrase, who was simply wanting a simple easy phrase to remember:

> “In speaking to corporate workers, I needed a way to get them to take breaks while at the same time allowing them to accomplish their work,” Dr. Anshel says. “The general ‘rule’ at the time was to take a 15-minute break every two hours. Yet most people with visual stress noticed problems earlier than two hours into their workdays.”
>
> Thus, the 20-20-20 Rule was born.
>
> Dr. Anshel says The Rule gives computer users a quick and easy “tag” to remember when using their computers.
>
> “The tag came from TV and radio interviews that time,” he says. “The interviewers asked what people can do about computer eyestrain, so I honed this into something easy to remember. I started with the ‘3B’ approach: blink, breathe, and break. Then the 20-20-20 Rule came out of the ‘break’ recommendation.”
>
> The basis behind the 20-20-20 Rule, according to Dr. Anshel, comes from studies that found benefits of shorter, more frequent breaks for musculoskeletal disorders.10-13 He adapted the information to the visual system.

Having said that, there seems to be a lack of actual studies that support the use of this rule as being better than no intervention. [One small study](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/36473088/)<sup>2</sup> published this year suggested no impact, a did a [larger study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC10391416/)<sup>3</sup>, though one paper in [African Vision and Eye Health](https://avehjournal.org/index.php/aveh/article/view/554/1316)<sup>4</sup> suggested a positive impact.

Refs:

1. Deconstructing the 20-20-20 Rule for digital eye strain. Optometry Times. Feb 22, 2018. https://www.optometrytimes.com/view/deconstructing-20-20-20-rule-digital-eye-strain. Accessed August 2023.
   Brian Chou.
2. Johnson S, Rosenfield M. 20-20-20 Rule: Are These Numbers Justified? Optom Vis Sci. 2023 Jan 1;100(1):52-56. doi: https://doi.org/10.1097/OPX.0000000000001971. Epub 2022 Dec 6. PMID: 36473088.
3. Datta S, Sehgal S, Bhattacharya B, Satgunam PN. The 20/20/20 rule: Practicing pattern and associations with asthenopic symptoms. Indian J Ophthalmol. 2023 May;71(5):2071-2075. doi: https://doi.org/10.4103/ijo.IJO_2056_22. PMID: 37203083; PMCID: PMC10391416.
4. Alghamdi, W., & Alrasheed, S. (2020). Impact of an educational intervention using the 20/20/20 rule on Computer Vision Syndrome. African Vision and Eye Health, 79(1), 6 pages. doi:https://doi.org/10.4102/aveh.v79i1.554